# ¿porque 4 es primo?

Tags: javascript, números-primos

Estoy aprendiendo JS y un ejercicio me pedia crear un codigo para saber si es primo o no, mi solucion fue

```javascript
function esPrimo(numero) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numero /2; i++){
    if (numero % i === 2 /*|| numero === 4*/) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

luego de investigar un poco porque no funcionaba del todo bien, vi que me faltaba una linea quedando asi

```javascript
function esPrimo(numero) {
  // Devuelve "true" si "numero" es primo
  // De lo contrario devuelve "falso"
  // Pista: un número primo solo es divisible por sí mismo y por 1
  // Pista 2: Puedes resolverlo usando un bucle `for`
  // Nota: Los números 0 y 1 NO son considerados números primos
  for (var i = 0; i < numero /2; i++){
    if (numero % i === 2 /*|| numero === 4*/) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return numero !== 1;
}
```

pero ahora ingreso el cuatro y el strout sale true (deberia ser false, ya que 4 no es primo), no logro entender el porque
¿algun enviado del cielo me explica?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! i solo vale 0 y 1... que esperas que haga con esos valores? ningun par es primo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se muy bien cual es tu razonamiento, pero lo que te falla en este caso no es Javascript sino más bien la logica que estás aplicando. Una solución para tu problema sería algo asi mejor:

```
function esPrimo(numero) {
  let divisores = 1; //El número siempre es divisor de si mismo entonces comienza en uno
  for (var i = 1; i <= numero /2; i++){ //Menor o igual en vez de menor estricto
    if (numero % i === 0) { //i es divisor de numero
      divisores++;
    }
  }
  return divisores == 2 //para ser primo debe ser divisible por si mismo y por 1
}
```

Una solución aún mejor para ahorrar iteraciones sería esta:

```
 function esPrimo(numero) {
      let divisores = 1; //El número siempre es divisor de si mismo
      let index = 1;
      while(divisores <= 2 && index <= numero/2){ 
        if (numero % index === 0) { //i es divisor de numero
          divisores++;
        }
        index ++;
      }
      return divisores == 2;
    }
```

Comment: Pro tip: Cuando buscas los divisores el límite no es `n/2`, es `sqrt(n)`. Buscar divisores mayores que la raíz cuadrada es un desperdicio porque la existencia de un divisor `a > sqrt(n)` implica la existencia de otro divisor `b < sqrt(n)`